# Layout issues when updating app to iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios7, xcode5

My App is nice and working fine in the app store. It even runs on iOS7 with no problems. However when I compile in Xcode 5 (for iOS7) its a disaster. The status bar is missing, the view is all stretched out, it doesn't pause where it should, and my third party advertiser's pop ups don't show up. Anyone know what's going on, at least with the status bar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app was previously build with the 6.0 SDK, which it will use even when running on a device with iOS 7. Now when you build with Xcode 5, you are building against the iOS 7.0 SDK, which introduces many changes from 6.0, and your app will look strange until you make necessary change to fit the paradigm of 7.0. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) is the official iOS 7 Transition Guide that explains how to cope with changes in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. Ugh, it's going to be a long process.

Comment: Not as bad as you might think. Edited with the link to the transition guide.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 is a significant update. This is a typical update to iOS 7 SDK scenario. You just need to work through each of the issues one by one.

The way the status bar is handled now is that it is always drawn (unless you hide it) over your content, so you have to provide the backdrop for the status bar. You have limited  control over the foreground color of the status bar - basically you can pick between white of black.

See: [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer here and up vote any answers that were helpful. It makes it easier for people to fin unanswered questions to answer and for others to find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 1):

Status bar issue can be solved by adding this value to plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "NO".

Comment: Yes, thanks. iOS7 isn't as difficult as I thought it would be.